# Trello OAuth only working with one Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth, trello

**Background**

- I am able to create Trello cards from Google Apps Script via the
  Trello API using the OAuth 1.0 library. The principle is proven/code
  works.
- I have two distinct Google Apps Scripts projects that need to be able to create Trello cards.
- The code in the two different Apps Scripts/Projects is identical - including the same API key/secret.
- *Only one Apps Script will create a Trello card.* This is my problem.
- If I reauthorise the other Apps Script, that script will work and the other will give me an API return of "invalid token" and vise-versa. Only one works at a time, but I need both to work.

**My thoughts**

- I think that Trello, via OAuth, see each Apps Script is its own distinct project.
- I think that because of this it won't let both apps use the same API key/secret to work with my Trello account. Only one project appears to be able to use the key/secret.
- If this is the case I don't know how to make each Apps Script its own project for the Trello API to work for both simultaneously.

**Help needed**

Does anyone know how to make this work? I need both scripts to be able to create Trello cards. I have a feeling that each apps needs to identify itself uniquely, but I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an OAuth logic issue, it's a feature, not a bug. In OAuth, your application exchanges refresh tokens for access tokens. The access tokens only have a limited life span.

When you use a refresh token to generate a new access token, you also get a new unique refresh token and your script stores this for future use, the old refresh token is no longer valid. Similarly, when you re-authorize the application, you get fresh tokens, and any previously generated tokens are rendered invalid.

So when you authorise one script using the same Client ID and Client secret as the other script, you get a new access token and refresh token, and the old credentials, stored by the other script, become invalid.

As a result, the other script can no longer exchange the refresh token it has stored for new access tokens, and it no longer works. Once you re-authorize this copy, the refresh token and access token in the other copy are invalidated in the same way.  So you end up going in circles.

You have two options:

- Set up a separate OAuth Client (with different Client ID and Client Secret) for each script.
- Modify your scripts to use the same storage location for the OAuth Access Token and Secret.

The first approach is going to give you the most reliable consistent results. If you try the second approach, you could still have cases where the scripts run at the exact same time, and one has valid tokens while the other tries to use the now invalid ones. (race conditions).